# How to migrate SSL from cPanel to Plesk?

Tags: ssl, cpanel, plesk

We're migrating a website from a different hosting provider whom uses cPanel to our server which uses Plesk.

I've attempted to copy the text of the private key and certificate over to the appropriate fields in Plesk and submitting; however, visiting the site using the HTTPS throws a "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" error.

I tried to find the CA certificate and it was not to be found in cPanel. I have the CSR, but there doesn't appear to be a place to put it in plesk.

What steps am I missing?

Comment: I'm quite certain your certificate will need to be re-issued . Assuming the cPanel is linux and Plesk on Windows?

Comment: Theyre both running on linux

Comment: Most likely re-issuing for the Plesk install will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using linux on both servers, instead of reissuing, you can just export the certificate from your cPanel and install it in Plesk.

I found some links that might help you with the installation: 
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1229840-install-certificate---plesk
http://www.sslshopper.com/plesk-8-ssl-installation-instructions.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Reina, The link you have given is only for to install ssl from plesk. I am unable to see any ssl exporting guidelines from cpanel to plesk. my apology if i have missed it.Anyway I have a thought regarding this. You can fetch the .crt and .key from the cpanel back end in the following locations.".key" is at /etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key and ".crt" at /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt. You will have the CAbundle also as /etc/ssl/certs/domain.cabundle.Copy all to notepad or any other editors and follow the steps in the link you have given earlier.I hope reinstallation of ssl will work.Try dude:)